# avoid function to fire twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function global(){

}
```

I have 2 pages, both of them included global.js which has above global function. I have to run global() in both place for certain reason, how to I prevent it from firing twice? like page 1 is layout, it will always run global() first. So if global already trigger, don't trigger it again when I visit page 2. page 3,4,5 etc will run global() of layout so it won't clash. My concern is the 2nd page.

Comment: I dont see that as a concern as the page reloads, all your scripts do so no question of firing twice. Show us what you have done already?

Comment: If the pages are loaded independently, why should you be concerned that `global()` will be fired twice? Otherwise you can prevent calling the function in page 2 at the first place.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal I have 2 js file, one is layout, one is its children. I need to run global() in both file.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your JS file is loaded only once, you can do the following:

You can assign a property to the function, just as you would with an object.

In the example below I add a property `executed` with a default value `false`. `executed` is set to `true` when the content of the function is executed, so the next time the function is called, the `if` statement will make sure the function returns immediately.

```js
function global() {
  if (global.executed) {
    return;
  }
  global.executed = true;
  // your code here ...
}
global.executed = false;
```

However, if both pages load the JS file independently, you will have to remember if the function is called somewhere static, for example in `localStorage`, in a cookie or on the server.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks.